# Create a temporary directory for multiple gradle tasks

Tags: windows, gradle, temporary-directory

I am working with gradle in a windows environment. I wish for my gradle script to create a temporary directory, different tasks to perform operations on it in various orders, and then delete it upon completion (optional). How can I create this temporary dir in the gradle script?

My initial thought was [Task.temporaryDir](https://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#org.gradle.api.Task:temporaryDir), however that directory only persists for the duration of the task.

Apologies if this is obvious, I am new to working on Windows and just picked up gradle yesterday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to create a temporary directory outside of project structure it can be done with adding:

```
def tempDir = File.createTempDir()
tempDir.deleteOnExit() // use with care, might be problematic with when daemon mode is used
```

e.g. somewhere at the beginning of the script.

Then the folder created can be used as an output directory elsewhere.

Comment: This `deleteOnExit()` would be unpredictable: just think about daemon/no-daemon mode.

Comment: Thanks, I keep forgetting that I can pretty much use java. Daemon mode is not an issue as I know when I need to delete the directory within the code as to not rely on deleteOnExit()

Answer (score 1):

If you need some task output to persist beyond the execution of the task then best to create a subfolder in the project build directory.

```
task myTask << {
    file("${buildDir}/foo").mkdirs()
}
```